# Would there be any fundamental flaw in a variable type that could hold generic classes of arbitrary T types?

Tags: c#, generics, language-design, type-safety

Imagine whenever you created a generic class `MyClass<T>`, an interface `MyClass<>` would automatically be generated which has all the methods and properties of `MyClass<T>` which don't use generic parameters or return values.

This would save me from so much work of creating one-off interfaces just to be able to handle generic objects of different `T` types. Is there a fundamental problem with the idea which is the reason it's not part of the language, or just a case of "it was not prioritized or considered important"?

When I say "interface" I don't mean that this would necessarily be classified as and called an "interface". It was just an easy way to explain what I mean. A kind of abstract base class would be another way to think about it. If this feature existed, you wouldn't think of it as interfaces being generated, just that e.g. a variable of type `List<>` can of course hold any generic List, like `List<int>` or `List<MyElement>` and you can then call things on it like `Count`, `Clear()`, `Capacity` etc. because those don't need knowledge of the type of `T`.

Just to make it clear why this is not a discussion thread but a question with a clear-cut answer:

My question is whether there's a flaw in the idea itself that renders it incompatible with type-safety or similar, or whether there are not any fundamental flaws in it.

Example of usage:

I have a generic class which contains both some data that depends on the generic type and some other data that don't. And I have code I want to be reusable that can manipulate the non-generic part of the data. Currently I can only do this by defining an interface that has the same members as my generic class (minus the members that use generic parameters or return values). Having to define this interface seems superfluous when I'm not intending to have more than one implementation. A language feature where the same could be done without specifying the extra interface, because the needed information is already in the generic class itself, would be handy for this case.

For simple cases, having a non-generic base class to the generic class is a common approach. However, if `MyClass<T>` is already inherited from `MyBaseClass<T>`, then putting a non-generic class in between is not possible, and only an interface can be used.

Comment: I've read your question three times and I still have absolutely no idea what you are asking.

Comment: I agree, what are you asking?

Comment: I'm asking if such a feature would be conceptually plausible to add to C#, or if there are fundamental flaws in the idea which means such a language feature could never be added to C#.

Comment: "such a feature" What feature? Maybe add a concrete code example to your question. I've never encountered something like you're describing.

Comment: I don't se why would you need such a feature. Maybe you using generics incorrectly? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: That seems like a pattern that might just be specific to your style. I don't see why the line is drawn between generic and non-generic components of the class. My interfaces are generally very short and address a specific behavior that I need. They never conform or are derived from a specific class.

Comment: I have used this approach a few times in C++; non-templated base to call through to polymorphic templated implementations.  Specifically in a home-rolled type system; abstract BaseType base and many derived SpecificType<T>. All access done through BaseType, some data stored in BaseType, other accessed through virtual calls, as made sense.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is whether there's a flaw in the idea itself that renders it incompatible with type-safety or similar, or whether there are not any fundamental flaws in it.

No, considering that you can create the base class/interface manually yourself, there is no reason a language couldn't create it automatically. (Whether it should is another question entirely.)

But if you built such language on .Net, you probably couldn't call it `MyClass<>`, because that is already used to represent open generic type (which makes `typeof(MyClass<>)` a valid expression).

Comment: I guess the natural followup question is "why can't we declare a variable of an open generic type?"

Comment: @Superpig Because no object could be assigned to such variable. If you're asking "why couldn't an object with some closed generic type be assigned to a variable whose type is the corresponding open generic type?", then I think that's a fairly non-trivial feature with questionable usefulness.

Comment: @svick That is the feature I had in mind. Since open generic types are currently unused in the language for variable type purposes, it should not conflict, and in my mind would be intuitive, if a closed generic object could be assigned to a variable of an open generic type. The open generic type is less restrictive than the object, just like an interface is less restrictive. When I first learned of open generic types I had assumed you could do just this.